# Tradeview: pinescript error: expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

I am getting below error when compiling below code in tradeview. Basically, I am trying to use EMA/SMA string to calculate MACD.

**line 20: mismatched input 'ema' expecting 'end of the line without line continuation'**

Can someone let me know what am I missing here? Is there any better way to code this?

Also, can we have multiple lines inside if-else statement or should I be having just oneliners?

```
study("MACD BB - PRD")

//MACD Inputs
//---------------------------------------------------------------
fastLength  =   input(defval=12,     title="MACD.FastPeriod",   minval=1, maxval=50,  step=1) 
slowLength  =   input(defval=26,     title="MACD.SlowPeriod",   minval=1, maxval=200, step=1)
signalLength=   input(defval=9,      title="MACD.SignalLength", minval=1, maxval=100, step=1)
macdMode    =   input(defval="EMA",  title="MACD.AverageMode",  options=["EMA","SMA"])

//Bollinger Bands Inputs
//---------------------------------------------------------------
bbPeriod    =   input(defval=9,      title="MACD.SignalLength",          minval=1, maxval=100, step=1)
bbMultipler =   input(defval=1,      title="MACD.SignalLength",          minval=1, maxval=10,  step=0.1)
bbMode      =   input(defval="EMA",  title="BollingerBands.AverageMode", options=["EMA","SMA"])

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// MACD calculation
macd = if (macdMode == "EMA")
ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowLength)  // line20
else
sma(close, fastLength) - sma(close, slowLength)
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with „apl“? Did you mean to use „api“?

Comment: if i can get this working on pine script, will translate same to API even

Comment: Maybe uppercase clarifies the difference: the tag „APL“ refers to a programming-language (that you probably did not intend to speak about). „API“ is an Application Programming Interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is *indentation*. You must shift the code inside of if statement's body by 4 spaces or 1 tab.

```
// MACD calculation
macd = if (macdMode == "EMA")
    ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowLength)  // line20
else
    sma(close, fastLength) - sma(close, slowLength)
```

> can we have multiple lines inside if-else statement or should I be
>   having just oneliners?

Yes.

There is a [Pine Script Tutorial](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Pine_Script_Tutorial) from TradingView that might help you.